# Center my navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So what I'm trying to do is have my navbar automatically center to anything that's in it.

What I want is:

- Logo all the way on the left (pulled left)
- Button all the way on the right (pulled right)
- Search bar directly in the center of the navbar

What I've been having problems with is that the button can have different width (because it's a button where your username is displayed) and this moves the search bar I have making it not centered.

Here's my current code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="./assets/img/test_logo.png" /></a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
          <div class="span4 offset1">
            <form class="navbar-form pull-right">
              <div class="input-append">
                <input class="span4" id="appendedInputButton" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <a class="button btn-active" href="" style="margin-top:5px" ><span><i class="icon-user"></i> Sign In</span></a>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:**
The width of the navbar should be 883px. The rest of the CSS should be Bootstrap's default.

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried CSS's `float` attribute?

Comment: add "margin:0 auto;" to input-append

Comment: @Gordan: `.pull-right` is defined by Bootstrap as `float: right` (and the same for `.pull-left`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as you've described, but that isn't what your code reflects.

Add `pull-left` to the `<a>` with the logo so it floats left. Get rid of `pull-right` from the `<form>` so it's not floating. Make sure both floating elements (the `<a>` and `<ul>` are defined *before* the `<form>`).

Comment: why before the <form>? (just curious)

Comment: @ShadyPotato Because the order of elements in the markup affects their position? If you place a floating element (e.g., the `<ul>`) after a block element (e.g., the `<form>`), the top of the floating element will align with the **bottom of the block element**, not the top of the container. If you didn't rearrange the markup, you would need to overcome this problem with CSS properties like `position` and `top`.

Answer (score 1):

you could float the elements, adjust the width. like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/smWBZ/

```
.logo {
    float:left;
}
```